# IOS - How to load array in property list

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, plist

Most of example for load data from plist is dictionary.
But I have a plist with array in 1st level data, like:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
....
....
....
</array>
</plist>
```

My question is how to load the data into an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Apply logic and deduction, then search the documentation of `NSArray`. If this fails, just google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *pListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plistName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *contentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Level1" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```